# Pass the user-agent through webdriver in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping, web-scraping, user-agent

I am working on a website scraping project using Selenium in Python. When I open the homepage through a browser, it opens properly.

But, when I try to open the webpage through `webdriver()` in Selenium, it opens a completely different page.

I think, it is able to detect the `user-agent`( not sure what it is called) and is able to check the properties of the browser or something.

Is it possible to pass the properties though the `webdriver()` so that the right homepage is loaded.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by " it opens a completely different page."?  A different url or the element on the site looks different?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Changing the user agent in the python version of webdriver is done by altering your browser's profile. I have only done this for `webdriver.Firefox()` by passing a profile parameter. You need to do the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override","your_user_agent_string")
driver=webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Every time you wish to change the user agent you will need to restart your web browser (i.e. call `driver=webdriver.Firefox(profile)` again)

If you are unsure to what your user agent string is do a search for "what is my user agent" on a browser that displays the page properly and just copy and paste that one.

Hope that sorts it.

Comment: So we MUST change the profile to change the user agent string? the reason i'm asking is because i need to maintain the session to avoid having to log in for every single instance i create

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the user-agent is the problem, in Java you can modify it like this:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.addAdditionalPreference("general.useragent.override", "some UA string");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

See documentation [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html).

Comment: So we MUST change the profile to change the user agent string? the reason i'm asking is because i need to maintain the session to avoid having to log in for every single instance i create