# Download image after auth through selelnium python

Tags: python, http, selenium

I am scraping a [webpage](http://www.badcaps.net/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=31) 
that requires you be logged in to see images and other attachments. I have everything else working in my script, but I cant figure out a way to download the images after logging the user in with Selenium.

An example of an image to download [here](http://www.badcaps.net/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=90063&d=1405263032).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading files with Selenium is possible by modifying your browser's default behavior. See [How to download a file using Selenium's WebDriver](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver). However, a more straight forward approach may be to use a client lib, such as `requests`, after you have authenticated via Selenium. You may access session related cookie values by calling [get_cookie(name)](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_cookie#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get_cookie) on your `webdriver` instance. You may then pass those values to `requests`:

```
import requests

...<selenium procedures>...

# URL for attachment
url = 'http://www.examplesite.tld/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=87690&stc=1&d=1401977404'

# Obtain session id from Selenium cookies
cookies = {
    'sessionhash': webdriver_instance.get_cookie('sessionhash'),
}

# User agent must match user agent used to create session
headers = {
    'User-Agent': <UA used by Selenium>,
}

response = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
attachment = response.content
```

If you need to change the user-agent used by Selenium, see [Pass the user-agent through webdriver in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286127/pass-the-user-agent-through-webdriver-in-selenium).

Comment: How would I save the attachment to a file?

Comment: `with open(filename, 'wb') as f: f.write(attachment)`

Comment: Hmm that's what I currently have but still cannot open the downloaded files.

Comment: What type, and how large of a file?

Comment: It works for me. Make sure you are using the correct cookie key, `sessionhash` is just an example. On your target site they use `bbsessionhash`. Also make sure you're using the same user-agent as Selenium and your browser. In my case that is `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36`. This should be enough for you to proceed, I will not demonstrate directly how to scrape your specific site.

Comment: I've already found a solution to my issue, however how did you find that they use `bbsessionhash`? Just for future knowledge.

Comment: Inspecting cookies via browser Developer Tools in Chrome.

Comment: How to download the pdfs?