# Open Firefox with definited headers

Tags: python, firefox, header

I'm looking to open Firefox programmatically with a Python program. The catch is I want full control over the headers being made in the initial request (all subsequent headers can be derived from the server response).

I was thinking about running the initial request through a local proxy and modifying the request that way. I wasn't sure how I could "turn it off" after the first request or not have Firefox relying on the program being open afterwards however.

Things like TamperData can achieve this within Firefox (with manual intervention) but again I'm looking at doing this programmatically.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the use case? Why do you need custom headers to be sent? Thanks.

Comment: It's for a PoC security application I wish to make. Information is captured by a incoming request (caused by XSS) with details such as the cookie, referer header, link etc. I want to launch Firefox to automatically hijack the session. Obviously this can be done manually via multiple methods right now - but I'm trying to create an automatic listener.

Comment: Have you eventually tried to go with selenium as the answer suggested? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/).

The idea is to start Firefox with a loaded [Modify Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/) extension and set it's preferences with custom headers you want to send. See more in the following blog post:

- [Changing HTTP headers for a Selenium WebDriver request](http://eveningsamurai.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/changing-http-headers-for-a-selenium-webdriver-request/)

Examples are in java, but can be transformed to Python appropriately.

---

Note that if the only header you need to change is `User-Agent` - it can be done via setting a firefox preference, quote from [Pass the user-agent through webdriver in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286127/pass-the-user-agent-through-webdriver-in-selenium):

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override","your_user_agent_string")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```