# Google blocking Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

I have a script where I am trying to search a google page via `selenium` to test something. Whenever I open up `Webdriver`, I get a captcha form:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=asdf')
```

However, if I open the exact same page, https://www.google.com/search?q=asdf, in a browser, it works fine. Why does Google raise the captcha, and what parameters can I send with `webdriver` such that it 'looks' like a normal browser and the captcha isn't raised?

Note, I have tried adding my user agent, and it still raises the same error:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("general.useragent.override","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

Here is an example of my Request headers from the normal browser:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass the user-agent through webdriver in Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286127/pass-the-user-agent-through-webdriver-in-selenium)

Comment: No, I would suggest removing the above "Similar Question", as this is an entirely different issue.

Comment: @David542, are you behind some sort of proxy?

Comment: webdrivers add fingerprints to the rendered source.  for example, firefox driver injects  "webdriver = True".  The issue has nothing to do with user agent being sent.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the user agent.
See this [SO ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286127/pass-the-user-agent-through-webdriver-in-selenium)

on using `set_preference`.

Comment: Please see revised question.

Comment: oh so you're still getting a captcha even passing user agent?

Comment: have you tried just setting `Mozilla/5.0` without the remaining string?

Comment: Yes, I still get that.

Comment: that's strange because I have no problem opening the driver with the exact same code above, and expected Request headers

Answer (score 0):

Pass all the headers using requests:

```
headers = {
    "Host": "www.google.com",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Cookie": "PREF=ID=0df7e6fbda0c09d3:U=bfc47b624b57a0e9:FF=0:TM=1414961297:LM=1414961298:S=2FtJad1BEeJ0M5XS; NID=67=t5zTrFVtG4cLZH2kVmsQEbqDRFJisM86z1s27zx0A6vTR0MWqg69DaY39muso6fIEgqnli7IaEv1Rge1ZxBG0Nr1_3KH1aLu_z1-Ar48oiVDFFSVX4KDRgWnHQWjUfHC",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer? I'd suggest being more verbose about what the solution is because this is clear as mud.